# "Сучить" и "засучить" — этимология

Tags: этимология

Можно сучить лен. Капризный ребенок, требуя у родителей очередную игрушку, катается по полу и сучит ногами. А еще можно засучить рукава.
Все это совершенно разные действия, а корень у слова один. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему разные? Везде идет некоторое скручивание и параллельное движение. По-моему эти действия вполне похожие. Судя по словарям, родственно "скать" - свивать, крутить, катать и т.п.